# I am unable to find repeated element in nested list in python. If anyone has best solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

the first three rows of the list of lists (shown belo) then ‘alfa-romero’ has 2 ‘convertible’ type and ‘alfa-romero’ has one ‘hatchback’.

I have this nested list, as input

```
cars = [['alfa-romero', 'convertible'],
['alfa-romero', 'convertible'],
['alfa-romero', 'hatchback'],
['audi', 'sedan'],
['audi', 'sedan'],
['audi', 'sedan'],
['audi', 'sedan'],
['audi', 'wagon'],
['audi', 'sedan']]
```

So, your output should be a list of lists like that
output will be this

```
[‘alfa-romero --- convertible’, 2]
[‘alfa-romero --- hatchback’, 1]
[‘audi --- sedan’,4]
```

Comment: Why is there an asterisk at the end of the list? If you want to unpack it you put one before, `[*[1,2,3]]` becomes `[1,2,3]` but `*[1,2,3]*` will give you a syntax error

Comment: Sorry it was written by mistake.  I have edit this.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using a dictionary. The indicated chosen output is not the most appropriate way of displaying the data. One way to filter out the list would be:

```
cars = [['alfa-romero', 'convertible'],
['alfa-romero', 'convertible'],
['alfa-romero', 'hatchback'],
['audi', 'sedan'],
['audi', 'sedan'],
['audi', 'sedan'],
['audi', 'sedan'],
['audi', 'wagon'],
['audi', 'sedan']]

cars_dict = {}
for car in cars: # loop through each car
    if not(car[0] in list(cars_dict.keys())): # if the make has not occurred before make dictionary
        cars_dict[car[0]] = {}
        cars_dict[car[0]][car[1]] = 1
    else:
        if car[1] in list(cars_dict[car[0]].keys()):
            cars_dict[car[0]][car[1]] += 1
        else: 
            cars_dict[car[0]][car[1]] = 1 #if the type has not occurred before than make dictionary
print(cars_dict)
```

Which outputs:

```
{'alfa-romero': {'convertible': 2, 'hatchback': 1}, 'audi': {'sedan': 5, 'wagon': 1}}
```

ie a dictionary of dictionaries. Accessed by car_dict[maker][type] . The keys of the first dictionary being the make of the car, and the keys of the second being the type of car.

If the output is required in the format you specified you could use the following to transform the cars_dict dictionary to the required_output list:

```
required_output = []
for maker in cars_dict.keys():
    for type_of_car in cars_dict[maker].keys():
        required_output.append([str(maker) + " --- " + str(type_of_car), cars_dict[maker][type_of_car]])
print(required_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to generate and append lists to an output list.

First, though, your input lists aren't valid in their current form... I'm going to assume we're starting with this input:

```
cars = [['alfa-romero --- convertible', 2],
    ['alfa-romero --- hatchback', 1],
    ['audi --- sedan',4]]
```

If not, we can address that issue separately, but your strings aren't valid strings, because those aren't single quotes, and your list of lists isn't itself a list.

step one is to split the strings into two separate strings. then you want to append those two strings as a list to your output list a given number of times.

```
output_list = []
for row in cars:
    make, style = row[0].split(' --- ')
    for n in range(row[1]):
        output_list.append([make, style])

print(output_list)
```

Alternatively, you can accomplish this in a more compact way like this:

```
    for row in cars:
        for n in range(row[1]):
            output_list.append(row[0].split(' --- '))
```